# IPB и интеграция

Tags: ipb, интеграция

Всем привет!Кароче говоря у меня есть форум, т.е. без портала. Собрался делать интеграцию с ДЛЕ или другой системой. Вопрос такой:Как сделать так, чтобы портал, который я собираюсь поставить, выводился на главной странице сайта т.е при заходе на site.ru, форум переехал на site.ru/forum или forum.site.ru, да и плюс к тому чтобы ссылки у текущих тем текущего форума не стали кривыми, то есть остались доступными. Быть может каким-нибудь редиректом? Просто я пока что вообще не имею представления как это сотворить.Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Экспортировать базу. Установить форум по новому адресу. Импортировать базу. С помощью SQL **UPDATE** изменить ссылки в сообщениях.
2. То же самое, но вместо обновления базы переписать URL через буферизацию вывода (**ob_start** и т.д.).

301-редиректом можно перенаправить все внешние запросы связанные с предыдущим адресом форума (с помощью правила на основе названий скриптов IPB).

Answer (score 1):

Ковырять базу не ЕСТЬ ГУД, пскольку у движка IPB имееются СОБСТВЕННЫЕ настройки и утиля.
Курим [тут](http://ipbskins.ru/forum/) и еще во многих местах.
Тема затерта до предела - почему Вы не смогли ничего найти, мне не понятно :( ...

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу никакой проблемы.

Для начала переместите файлы форума туда, куда вам нужно. В папку ./forum или в субдомен forum.site.loc; Если у вас новая база данных, то далее запустите phpMyAdmin и импортируйте базу данных форума.

Потом откройте файл conf_global.php и отредактируйте пути до сайта, согласно с новым положением файлов и данные для соединения с базой данных (если у вас новая база данных).

Форум IPB заработает. Не забудьте перейти в панель управления форума и изменить пути для сохранения файлов и путь до папки temp в глобальных настройках.